# Object expected error message in Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

```
<script type="application/javascript" language="javascript">
    function showElement(elementID, show){
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    if (element) {
      element.className = (show ? element.className.replace(/hidden/gi, "show") : element.className + " hidden");
     }
    }
</script>
        
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%">  
            <tr class="baseGrayMedium">
                <td colspan="2">
                    (<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showElement('evicChkLst',true);" class="nostyle">+</span></a>|<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showElement('evicChkLst',false);" class="nostyle">-</span></a>) &nbsp;&nbsp; <B>Eviction Checklist</B>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I get the Javascript error saying object expected and it points to `onClick` event in the HTML code.. Could some one suggest me why so?

EDIT:

```
<script type="application/javascript" language="javascript">
                function showElement(elementID, show){
                    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
                    if (element) {
                        element.className = (show ? element.className.replace(/hidden/gi, "show") : element.className + " hidden");
                    }
                }
            </script>
            
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%">     
                <tr class="baseGrayMedium">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        (<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showElement('evicChkLst',true);" class="nostyle">+</span></a>|<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showElement('evicChkLst',false);" class="nostyle">-</span></a>) &nbsp;&nbsp; <B>Eviction Checklist</B>
                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Now the code looks some thing like the above

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is: `<script type="application/javascript" language="javascript">`
It must be `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">`

Answer (score 2):

I don't immediately see anything wrong in your snippet.

It's possible that formatting elsewhere in your script has messed up the definition or scope of `showElement`. Try adding this link next to the others:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert(typeof showElement);">?</a>
```

It should alert `function` if everything up to that point is good (or, at least, ***not*** alert `undefined`).

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error and it was because I had a form element that was trying to submit to an action that was invalid.

Mine was  and that was not a valid action.

If you are still having this error you should verify syntax as well as that your form is submitting to a valid method.

This error indicates bad html syntax or invalid source.