# Can't block keys using event listener

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, firefox

```
<body id="body" runat="server" onkeydown="return showKeyCode(event)">
```

Now whenever I hit a key, IE8 (or in comp mode) throws an exception directing to a problem
in line x, which happens to be my body tag. How can I prevent that ?
The JS code to my knowledge should be with IE comp. (works in Chrome)
Moreover the code doesn't work in IE and Firefox (it doesn't block F5 and Enter)

--> Object expected

```
var version = navigator.appVersion;

function showKeyCode(e) {
    var keycode = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

    if ((version.indexOf('MSIE') != -1)) {
        if (keycode == 13) {
            event.keyCode = 0;
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (keycode == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another problem I'm facing is with this simple JS in IE & FF (works in Chrome):

Nothing happens & --> Object expected

```
 <a onclick="ClearTextboxes();" title="Close" id="close" runat="server">Close</a>

....in script tags:
 function ClearTextboxes() {
     document.getElementById('<%= txtbox_name.ClientID %>').value = '';
     document.getElementById('<%= txtbox_email.ClientID %>').value = '';
     document.getElementById('<%= txtbox_content.ClientID %>').value = '';
     document.getElementById('<%= ResultMail.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';

 }
```

Comment: *Please please* always tell us *what* error message you get exactly. It is awfully annoying to have to guess every time.

Comment: Get rid of that "javascript:" while you're waiting for a real answer.

Comment: -First post updated with error messages
-Removing "javascript:" didn't change a thing.

Comment: @dll32 I didn't expect it would, but it's useless and kind-of wrong.

Comment: This post any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676029 ?

Comment: “it doesn't block F5” → Indeed, it shouldn't. Can you post a link to a real page containing this code, I'm getting confused of those ASP.NEP things.

Comment: If the error is pointing to the body tag, most of the time, it means the JS engine cannot find the reference to the function that you wanted executed. Could you post full page source code. Verify that your javascript code is inside the head element, or at least before the body element.

Comment: @Ilya Volodin: Posting the full page source is generally not very constructive (this is not a website for code reviews). Posters should be encouraged to try to drill down and isolate the problem area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary code in your `showKeyCode` function. The following will do just as well; you're already guaranteed that `e` will refer to the key event object becuase of the way you're passing in `event` in the body's `onkeydown` attribute, and there's no need for any browser sniffing at all. `return false` is the correct way to prevent the browser's default action when using a DOM0 key handler, so no need for `e.returnValue`.

You'll have problems blocking F5 and unless you have a seriously good reason you shouldn't do it anyway, since the user is used to it performing a page refresh. If you change the function to the following then there's no reason why it shouldn't prevent the Enter key's default action:

```
function showKeyCode(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't block F5, use a onbefore unload handler to make sure the user knows they are going to lose changes, they can cancel the refresh if they want to. This will work for back button, close window, navigate away.

I would strongly consider using jquery, ext-core, prototype which do the normalization of keyboard event data for you.

The best reference with keyboard handling across platforms/browsers http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: There's no need for a framework for this. My answer will work in all the major browsers released in the last decade.

Comment: I made a huge mistake when I started this project...I used XHTML-compliant script tags, instead of the usual <script></script> which seems to explain why these scripts were working in Chrome and in none of the other browsers...